# Check if API controller method has authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to determine whether API method has authorize attribute and although I can easily find that using `MethodInfo`, I can't seem to find a way to handle check when `Authorize` is set on controller level.

Basically I need to know if either controller or method has `Authorize` attribute.

```
public class SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAuthorizeAttribute = context.MethodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Any();

        if (!hasAuthorizeAttribute)
        {   
            operation.Security = new List<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to find a way to find if method has either controller or method `Authorize` attribute.

```
var hasAuthAttribute = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
            .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
            .Any();
```